# In InnoSetup how to stop all running exe during upgrade

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, pascal

During upgrade how to stop or kill running exe's and replace new version exe's during silent installation without any message box. Is it better to kill all task in [UninstallRun] Section or any other section.

Comment: IMO, never ever kill any processes silently, without asking user for permission! Such a software and software provider would not be long lived on my system.

Comment: Ok fine, If so after getting permission how to kill any process during upgrade.