# Forcefully kill all exe during upgrade in innosetup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

During Upgrade in innosetup I'm trying to taskkill existing exe's and copy into new folder bin_backup and start new exe's copy to bin, problem is during copying new exe's to bin i want to check whether all exe's are killed in taskmanager even i forcefully try to start exe's it should not allow to copy instead it has to replace back old exe's present in bin_back up to bin.

Comment: Why are you implementing all this, when Inno Setup does it for you? See [my answer to Kill process before (re)install using “taskkill /f /im” in Inno Setup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33777149/850848) (I actually [gave you that link already](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39566749/850848)). If you have some problem with the built-in functionality, you should explain us, what that problem is.

Comment: Problem is during upgrade old exe's gets replaced in bin_backup folder, this is done by as you said in [UninstallRun] Section. Again during copying new exe's in bin folder i have to cross check again whether any exe's is running again.

Comment: How's `UninstallRun` involved in upgrade? Sorry, but I just do not understand. Relevant parts of your script may help understanding.

Comment: Can you tell how to know whether a process is running in TaskManager in innosetup.

Comment: If your actual question is *"how to know whether a process is running"*, ask it. Though I still really doubt you need to know it.